# Unable to execute a main method in Intellij Idea CE on Ubuntu

Tags: intellij-idea, adoptopenjdk

I'm trying to get familiar with Intellij Idea CE. The platform is 32bit xubuntu 18.04 and AdoptOpenJDK 1.8.0_272. I wrote a simple "Hello World" program and I see some incomprehensible errors when I execute "Run Bootstrap.main()" on the context menu. Attached the screen shot for reference:[image]

1: /home/deepakna/Bin/jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_272/bin/java: cannot open ��m�u/.��LkS�: No such file

1: /home/deepakna/Bin/jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_272/bin/java: ELF: not found

5: /home/deepakna/Bin/jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_272/bin/java: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

[image]

Comment: Looks like there are some non-unicode characters in classpath. Please provide full executed command from build output.

Comment: @y.bedrov I've attached the full execution command as an image attachment to the question.

Comment: Please try to add "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" into "Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Shared build process VM options". Also please share idea.log and build.log after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a JDK installed?

This could also be a typical Linux/Ubuntu error.

It also looks like IntelliJ cannot read the code properly in the 1st row.

Comment: Yes, there is AdoptOpenJDK installed. It's visible in the screen shot.